# when I use "modify" on my timestamp it gives a wrong output

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I want to block a someone who tried to login 4 times with a wrong password.

The problem is: When I use "modify" and change the timestamp with 15 minutes, I get `-1` as output and after two minutes I get `-2` as output. I tied for so long and I searched a lot on internet, but it still doesn't work.

**How I want it to work:** 
In the database is the column: "falselog". If the username of the visiter is correct but the password is incorrect, falselog will be +1. When falselog is 4, the visiter will be banned for 15 minutes. So the visiter is able to try 4 times. After 15 minutes, the visiter can try again.

This is my object with all the code:

```
public function logUser($username, $password) { 

    // query id = 2     
    $sql2_1 = "SELECT 
            id, 
            password, 
            falselog, 
            lastlogin
        FROM users
        WHERE username ='".$username."' ";

    $result2_1 = $this->con->query($sql2_1);
    $fetch2_1  = mysqli_fetch_array($result2_1);
    $count2_1  = $result2_1->num_rows; 

    $now          = new DateTime('now');    
    $blockedSince = new DateTime($fetch2_1['lastlogin']);

    $fout     = $fetch2_1['falselog'];
    $date_old = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("now")); 

    $block    = date("i", $fetch2_1['lastlogin']) + 16;         
    $current  = date("i", strtotime("now"));
    $wait     = $block - $current ; 
    $dbtime   = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date_old));


    // This is the code that doesn't work
    if ($fetch2_1['falselog']>=4 AND $blockedSince->modify('+15 minutes') > $now) {
        $error[] = 'This account has been banned, try again about '.$wait.' minutes';
        $decline = true;  
        $date_old = $fetch2_1['lastlogin']; 
    } 

    elseif (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9-]+$/", $username)) { 
        $error[] = 'De input bevat ongeldige tekens (alleen cijfers en letters toegestaan)';
    } 

    elseif ($count2_1 === 0) {
        $error[] = 'Wrong login data';
    } 

    elseif ($fetch2_1['password']!=sha1($password)) {
        $error[] = 'wrong password';
        $fout = $fetch2_1['falselog']+1;
    } 

    if ((count($error) == 0) OR ($fetch2_1['falselog']==4 AND $blockedSince->modify('+15 minutes') < $now)) {
        $fout = 0; 
    }

    $sql2_2 = "UPDATE users SET 
            falselog='".$fout."', 
            lastlogin='".$dbtime."'
        WHERE username='".$username."' ";

    if ($this->con->query($sql2_2) === TRUE) {

        if (count($error) == 0) {
            return false; 
        } 

        else {
            return $error; 
        }
    } 

    else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql2_2 . "<br>" . $this->con->error;
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am trying to make the login for my website secure" - `WHERE username ='".$username."'` - `sha1($password)` - Maybe you should first fix the basics.

Comment: Can you explain that to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that here

```
$blockedSince = new DateTime($fetch2_1['lastlogin']);
```

you get the correct data for DateTime, try var_dump($blockedSince); after this line, and check that it has correct value inside;

Comment: It works correctly, thanks! only this: "This account has been suspended, try again about -50 minutes" This is the output of the error. The time comes from "$wait". I will try to fix it myself now! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this
$blockedSince = mktime($fetch2_1['lastlogin']);